# Need to break out a config method into its own namespace so it can have multiple configurations

Tags: ruby, active-directory, sinatra

So I have a `Sinatra::Base` application that connects to Active Directory, and everything works perfect when there is only one Active Directory being queried against. However now I have three Active Directories that I need to query against, and that has gotten me stuck.

Is there a way to hide `ActiveDirectory::Base.setup(active_directory_settings)` inside a module, so that whenever the specific active directory needs to be called, I can choose which one to connect to?

```
## app.rb file

module AD
  class API < Sinatra::Base
    # ...
    configure do
      # ...
      active_directory_settings = {
        host: '000.000.00.0',
        base: 'DC=example,DC=local',
        port: 389,
        auth: {
          method: :simple,
          username: 'ad_user@example.com',
          password: 'p@ssword'
        }
      }
      ActiveDirectory::Base.setup(active_directory_settings)

    end

    # ...
  end
end
```

launching app using config.ru

```
## config.ru

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require(:default)

require './app.rb'
run Rack::Cascade.new [AD::API]
```

in a rakefile because the config settings are set I can call the following, and it will connect with the settings specified in the config block,

```
## Rakefile

## How it works right now
task :query do

  everyone = ActiveDirectory::User.find(:all, department: '*')
  everyone.each do |user|
   puts user.displayName ## returns all the active directory usernames
  end

end

## How im trying to get it to work
task :query2 do

  first_ad = FirstAD::ActiveDirectory::User.find(:all, department: '*')
  first_ad.each do |user|
    puts user.displayName
  end

  second_ad = SecondAD::ActiveDirectory::User.find(:all, department: '*')
  second_ad.each do |user|
    puts user.displayName
  end

end
```

Comment: I don't know what Active Directory is but can't you just mount three Sinatra module apps into one app with three different routes? You could iterate through all three configs and even use the same app with different configs and different mount points.